# Ошибка в программе Си при выполнении цикла

Tags: c

При попытке подсчёта суммы чисел в цикле в конце программы происходит ошибка и программа перестаёт выводить что-либо.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int n, f, k, max_i;
    float x, h, a, sum, *r;

    r = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    h = 2.2;
    a = 3.2;
    x = 4.1;
    f = 0;
    n = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        r[i] = cos(i*h) - cos(a*x+i*h);
        if (r[i] < 0 && f == 0)
        f = i+1;
    }

    max_i = r[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        if (r[i] > max_i)
            max_i = i;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%f ", r[i]);

    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = f; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (r[i] < 0)
            r[i - cnt] = r[i];
        else
            cnt ++;
    }

    k = n - cnt;
    float *tmp = realloc(r, k * sizeof(float));
    r = tmp;

    for (int i = max_i; i < k; i ++)
    {
        sum += r[i];
    }

    printf("%f", sum);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас мусор в переменной `n`, и после выделения памяти вы присваивает ей значение, сделайте это до выделения памяти.

Answer (score 2):

```
int n, f, k, max_i;
float x, h, a, sum, *r;
r = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
```

Скажите, *сколько* памяти вы выделяете в `malloc`?

Вот и ответ...