# Соединение двух массивов СИ

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int len1=0,len2=0,lenc=0,k=0,o=0,i=0;
    printf("Input the length of the first array: ");
    scanf("%d", &len1);
    int c1[len1];
    printf("Input the length of the second array: ");
    scanf("%d", &len2);
    lenc=len1+len2;
    int c2[lenc];
    for(i=1; i<=len1; i++){
        printf("A[%d]=", i);
        scanf("%d", &c1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int k=1; k<=len2; k++){
        printf("B[%d]=", k);
        scanf("%d", &c1[k]);
    }
    lenc=len1+len2;
    int c3[lenc];
    k=1;
    for(i=0; i<len1; i++){
        c3[k++] = c1[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i<len2; i++){
        c3[k++] = c2[i];
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<lenc;i++){
        printf("c[%d]= %d ", i,c3[i]);
    }   


    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Почему то в последнем цикле где вывожу весь получившийся массив, выводит непонятные значения всегда, а не те которые я ввёл. Буду рад если поясните что не так )

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, массивы нумеруются с нуля, во-вторых - в с2 никто ничего не вводит

Comment: На ответ не тянет.

Comment: Так бывает, что код с исправленными ошибками не несёт никакой пользы сообществу, поэтому здесь достаточно выявить ошибки, [не так ли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328816/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%A1%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0/1328825#1328825)

Answer (score 1):

проблем куча:

1. в "си" первый элемент массива имеет нулевой индекс
2. некорректно используются переменные

Рабочий прилизанный код выглядит так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int len1 = 0, len2 = 0;

    printf("Input the length of the first array: ");
    scanf("%i", &len1);

    int c1[len1];

    printf("Input the length of the second array: ");
    scanf("%i", &len2);
    int c2[len2];

    for(int i = 0; i < len1; i++){
        printf("A[%d]=", i);
        scanf("%d", &c1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < len2; i++){
        printf("B[%d]=", i);
        scanf("%d", &c2[i]);
    }

    int len_total = len1 + len2;

    int c3[len_total];
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        c3[k++] = c1[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
        c3[k++] = c2[i];
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < len_total; i++) {
        printf("c[%d]=%i, ", i, c3[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```